# Generating GridView rows dynamically based on TextBox input

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dynamic

I am currently have a `gridview` with no row, only header. I have an ASP control `textbox` with a `OnTextChange` event. So everytime I input into a number into the `textbox`, my gridview will generate number of rows based on it. And inside the row, will have a `dropdownlist`

For instance, in my `textbox`, I type number `2`, 2 rows will be generated in the gridview.

I am currently using ASP.NET

Textbox:

```
[  2 ]
```

GridView:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| S/N |                      |                     |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1  |   [dropdownlist]     |     [dropdownlist]  |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|  2  |   [dropdownlist]     |     [dropdownlist]  |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to get you started. Inside your GridView you can use `<TemplateField>` to create the layout you want. After that you might want to look into the `OnRowDataBound` event to fill the DropDownLists.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = 0;

    //get the number from the textbox and try to convert to int
    try
    {
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    //set the new rowcount as a viewstate so it can be used after a postback
    ViewState["rowCount"] = rowCount;

    //start the function to fill the grid
    fillGrid();
}

private void fillGrid()
{
    int rowCount = 0;

    //get the current row count from the viewstate
    if (ViewState["rowCount"] != null)
    {
        rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["rowCount"]);
    }

    //create a new DataTable with three columns.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Created", typeof(DateTime));

    //loop to add the row to the table
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
         table.Rows.Add(0, "Name_" + i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i));
    }

    //bind the table to the grid
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```